# Skype Channel: Unable to login with 'Sign in' to save your chat

Tags: botframework, skypedeveloper

I have enabled Skype channel for my bot which on top of chat window shows option to login. I am unable to login using my work ID, rather I could login with my personal Microsoft account.

[image]

I could not find much documentation on this. How can I enable bot so that bot users can login only with their work email id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior as [Skype](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/create-a-skype-account-with-business-email/42b6c6e8-67e4-4595-8c94-451ee28def1f) doesn't let you create an account anymore with a business email address. If you want to test your bot by connecting it to Skype channel, then you can use your personal account. The [Skype for Business](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-skypeforbusiness?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) channel is specifically designed for the usage of work email ID but it is being deprecated on the Bot Framework. I would suggest you to connect the bot to [Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-overview) to login using work email ID.

Comment: If I were to deploy my bot to SharePoint sites then the only way is via Skype channel. I wonder if there is a way to remove sign in option because I do not want users to use their personal account.

Comment: Just to get more clarity, when you say you want to deploy your bot to Sharepoint sites, do you want to have the bot's UI on Sharepoint or access the bot from Sharepoint's site?

Comment: I'm not sure of the difference but with Skype channel I can embed bot to SharePoint sites using spfx/Content editor web-part and then it starts to show up on bottom right corner of the site.

Comment: You can make use of the Direct Line channel for the same. Please refer to https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51621.sharepoint-framework-spfx-microsoft-bot-framework-integration.aspx , https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-bot-framework and https://blog.getbizzy.io/add-bizzy-to-your-sharepoint-site-using-spfx-ab7ed97b856c. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Okay, I will try those and keep you posted. In the meantime, I will accept this answer. Thank you